# What is the "rails way" to access a parent object's attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

Let's say I have a model `Doctor`, and a model `Patient`. A `Patient belongs_to a Doctor`.

A `Doctor` has an attribute `office`.

I would want to, given a `Patient p`, be able to say `p.office` and access the `office` of `p`'s Doctor.

I could always write a method

```
class Patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    def office
        self.doctor.office
    end
```

But is there a more automatic way to expose all of the `Doctor`'s attribute methods to the `Patient`? Perhaps using `method_missing` to have some kind of catch-all method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use **[delegate](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate)**.

```
class Patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    delegate :office, :to => :doctor
end
```

You could have multiple attributes in one delegate method.

```
class Patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    delegate :office, :address, :to => :doctor
end
```

Comment: So what if, in addition to `office`, I had 10 other attributes I wanted to "delegate" to the `doctor`? Would I have to write 10 `delegate` declarations?

Comment: @Tim You could only write one.

Comment: I see, I didn't read carefully and realize you can pass multiple fields to delegate. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are talking about using Patient as a delegator for Doctor.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :doctor

  delegate :office, :some_other_attribute, :to => :doctor
end
```

I think this would be the method_missing way of doing this:

```
def method_missing(method, *args)
  return doctor.send(method,*args) if doctor.respond_to?(method)
  super
end
```