# In Rails 4, how to build a login form with a delegate attribute (parent attribute)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Rails is still new to me.  I'm trying to build a login form that use a "delegate" attribute. I have read those posts : [Rails delegate method](http://blog.wyeworks.com/2009/6/4/rails-delegate-method/) and [access-a-parent-objects-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878792/what-is-the-rails-way-to-access-a-parent-objects-attributes). I'm using Devise and trying to modify "devise/sessions/new.html.erb".

The model.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  delegate :clientcode, to: :client
end
```

The login form.

```
<%= form_for (resource, as: => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :clientcode %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

A user must log in with *users.username*, *users.password*, but also with *clients.clientcode* (can't change that, this is a feature) in the same login form.

I have an error "[...] delegated to client.clientcode, but client is nil [...]".  Why Rails accept that my *user* is not created yet (no problem with *username* field), but don't do the same for *clientcode* ?

How I'm suppose to do a form using a delegate (parent) attribute ?

Comment: You can use
delegate :clientcode, to: :client, allow_nil: true
and then associated it to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because the action :new creates an empty User with no Client associated to it.

```
2.1.0p0 :012 > @user = User.new
 => #<User:0x000001018ff348> 
2.1.0p0 :013 > @user.username
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :014 > @user.pass
 => nil 
2.1.0p0 :015 > @user.client
 => nil
```

Now, to solve your problem, I recommend you to create a non persisted attribute in you User model and then match it with your clients in the controller. I don't think Devise is your best friend for this task.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  delegate :clientcode, to: :client

  attr_accessor :temp_clientcode
end

class SessionController < ApplicationController

  def create
    ...
    @user = Client.where(clientcode: params[:temp_client_code]).first.users.where(username: params[:username], password: params[:password]).first
    ...
  end

end

<%= form_for (resource, as: => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :temp_clientcode %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= f.submit "Sign in" %>
<% end %>
```

Of course this code is terrible and shouldn't be used, but it gives you the idea.

Also, it's woth mentioning that Ryan Bates recorded some nice screencasts on the subject. Got some links for you

[Authentication from scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch)

[Authentication with Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-devise-revised)

Let me know if this is somewhat clear to you.